# Adding my application in keycloak as identity provider

Tags: openid, keycloak

I already have several separate identity servers, each one providing access token for a username and a password. I need to integrate all of them together without changing anything in their DB or code (considering both as black boxes). I was thinking of using Key cloak to achieve this which has many features like adding broker identity provider, user federation, REST API, etc. Can you guide on what feature is best to use in this case? 
The purpose is to keep the ability of using one of the multiple credentials per user but allowing one authentication to let the user access all the servers. We are using open ID connect with identity server.

Comment: Can you give detail ? Do you add an openid provider (your own auth app, "an openid provider") to keycloak ?

Comment: I tried the broker provider described in https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.2/server_admin/topics/identity-broker/overview.html but it just redirected me from realm account page to my website login page without creating a keycloak user and a keycloak access token